# Modify css react component with styled-component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am consuming some component from library which are not in my project repo. Since I am using `styled-component` to develop my own component. I want to do little modification on component which I am consuming from other library without touching there code base. Here is little example of what I am trying to achieve but none of following style is getting applied to `CustomCom`

**UI Library**

```
const CustomCom = ()=>{
  return (
    <div>Child</div>
  );
}
```

**My Repo**

```
export default styled(CustomCom)`
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only possible if the component passes `className` to the DOM element, per the `styled-components` documentation

> The styled method works perfectly on all of your own or any
>   third-party components, as long as they attach the passed className
>   prop to a DOM element.

https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-components

Here's some sample code, which of course modifies the Library code, which I understand you can't do, but you could fork the library and do it if you want.

```
const CustomCom = ({className})=>{
  return (
    <div className={className}>Child</div>
  );
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const MyElem = styled(CustomCom)`
      height: 20px;
      background: green;
    `
    return (
      <MyElem />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try below

```
export const newCustom  = styled(CustomCom)`
height: 20px;
background: green;
`;
```

Now use this custom component

```
<newCustom   />
```

If you want to extend existing HTML tags you can do this:

```
export const newCustom  = styled.div`
height: 20px;
background: green;
`;
```

Comment: This is exactly the code they have in their question and doesn't fix the issue they're having, which is using `styled-components` on a 3rd party component that doesn't pass forward `className`